# Deploying NodeJS application to Openshift

Tags: node.js, openshift, sails.js

I have working SailsJS app that I want to deploy to Openshift, but as usual it doesn't go smoothly.
Here's what I did so far:

```
rhc app create myApp nodejs-0.10
rhc cartridge add mongodb-2.4
```

After these two, I can see that app is created and when I visit given URL, I got Welcome page.

I installed RockMongo, and I see that I can visit my mongodb as well.

Since I already have code, I proceed with following:

```
git remote add openshift -f <openshift-git-repo-url>
git merge openshift/master -s recursive -X ours
git push openshift HEAD
```

After I merge my existing code with remote openshift (like in commands above), things start to go wrong.

When I visit url to application, I receive 503 Service temporarily unavailable. If I visit RockMongo and try to login with given credentials, I receive

```
Unable to connect MongoDB, please check your configurations. 
MongoDB said:Failed to connect to: 127.10.37.130:27017: Transport endpoint is not connected.
```

Also, in Applications Panel, status of my application is building (and stays like that for hours). After pushing code to openshift, application stopped, and after rebuilding it (automatically) I receive some errors, where the last one is

```
remote: An error occurred executing 'gear postreceive' (exit code: 34)
remote: Error message: CLIENT_ERROR: Failed to execute: 'control build' for /var/lib/openshift/538f1c205004461655000227/nodejs
```

Does anyone has idea what's going on?

Maybe I didn't set up ports, application url, db url properly? But then again, why RockMongo stopped working?

### UPDATE

Here's my mongo config:

```
 mongo: {
   module: 'sails-mongo',
   user: 'admin',
   password: '********',
   url: process.env.OPENSHIFT_MONGODB_DB_URL + 'surge'
 }
```

Do I need to set up `server_port = process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_PORT` and `server_ip_address = process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_IP` as well?
I have some server.js file in root of my application, and I see that these variables are used here.

Here's what I get if I run `env | grep NODEJS`

```
OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_PATH_ELEMENT=/var/lib/openshift/538f1c205004461655000227//.node_modules/.bin:/opt/rh/nodejs010/root/usr/bin
OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_PORT=8080
OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_LD_LIBRARY_PATH_ELEMENT=/opt/rh/nodejs010/root/usr/lib64
OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_IDENT=redhat:nodejs:0.10:0.0.17
OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_LOG_DIR=/var/lib/openshift/538f1c205004461655000227/app-root/logs/
OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_IP=127.10.37.129
OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_PID_DIR=/var/lib/openshift/538f1c205004461655000227/nodejs//run/
OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_VERSION=0.10
OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_DIR=/var/lib/openshift/538f1c205004461655000227/nodejs/
```

and here's what I get for  `env | grep mongo`:

```
OPENSHIFT_ROCKMONGO_DIR=/var/lib/openshift/538f1c205004461655000227/rockmongo/
PHPRC=/var/lib/openshift/538f1c205004461655000227/rockmongo/etc/conf/php.ini
OPENSHIFT_ROCKMONGO_IDENT=redhat:rockmongo:1.1:0.0.12
OPENSHIFT_MONGODB_IDENT=redhat:mongodb:2.4:0.2.11
OPENSHIFT_MONGODB_DB_URL=mongodb://admin:PASSWORD_HERE@127.10.37.130:27017/
OPENSHIFT_MONGODB_DIR=/var/lib/openshift/538f1c205004461655000227/mongodb/
```

Comment: Try supplying us some code?  Like your MongoDB connection string (remove the username/password).  It is also likely that you are trying to bind to 0.0.0.0 or localhost which is not allowed.

Comment: Hi, I just updated my answer. I also feel like there is some config thing that I missed, but can't figure out what is the problem :/

Comment: Yes, you need to set the ip and port to bind to, probably why your application is not starting up.  Also use rhc tail to check your log files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just in case someone else stumbles upon this problem, here is what I had to do.

I created separate file config/application.js, and there I placed

```
module.exports = {
  port: process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_PORT,
  host: process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_IP,
  environment: 'production'
};
```

Also I found what was the problem with application not starting. Post-install was failing (bower install did not finish successfully). To fix it, one should add to scripts section of package.json

```
"postinstall": "export HOME=/var/lib/openshift/[instance-id]/app-root/runtime/repo; ./node_modules/bower/bin/bower install"
```

Comment: what is the instance-id exactly?

Comment: uf, it's been a while, and I'm not working with Node anymore, but I would say it's an instance you get once you create application on OpenShift. Let me know if that's not true, I'll try to dig into that code.

Comment: yeah its the id of the openshift user (can be retrieved by the USER environment variable)

Comment: phew, I honestly don't remember, I don't think I had problems with RockMongo.